# How to assign vertex attributes to only one mode in a bipartite network in statnet?

Tags: networking, attributes, vertex, bipartite, statnet

I am currently working with a bipartite network with two distinct modes and two distinct sets of attributes. So row 1 through 5 is a mode and actors A, B and C are a different mode who form some connection marked by a 1.

```
    a<-replicate( 3, numeric(5) )
    b<-apply(a, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1))
    rownames(b) <- rownames(c(1,2,3,4,5))
    colnames(b) <-colnames(c("A","B","C"))
    b
            A    B    C
    [1,]    1    0    1
    [2,]    1    0    1
    [3,]    0    0    0
    [4,]    0    1    1
    [5,]    1    1    0
c<-as.network(b, directed=T, bipartite =3)

    e<-c('A',"B","C")
    f<-c('tall','short','tall')
    g<-data.frame(e,f)
    colnames(g)<-c('person','height')
    g
      person height
          A   tall
          B  short
          C   tall
```

How do I assign the height attribute from data frame g to only the actors A, B and C?
So far, I have tried set.vertex.attribute according to the position of the vertices of A, B and C

```
set.vertex.attribute(c, attrname= 'height', g$height, v = network.vertex.names(c)[6:9])
```

but I get the following error

```
Vertex ID does not correspond to actual vertex in set.vertex.attribute.
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I figured this out. I was having the same problem myself with a bipartite network and I borrowed some code from an iGraph tutorial.

```
set.vertex.attribute(c,attrname = "height", 
                  value = as.character(g$height), 
                  v= match(c %v% "vertex.names",g$person))
```

This worked for me, not sure if the as.character will be necessary for you or not. You're referring to the vertices you want by using the name statnet knows them by "vertex.names".